# Synchronizing GitHub repo with Airflow dags

Tags: git, synchronization, airflow, github-actions

I have a GitHub repository to which changes are pushed, I want to synchronize all the files in the repo to my airflow dags but using '**Git Actions**' only. So far i was able to checkout and get the repo files ready but the problem i encountered is how to push the files to the dags. The following code is what i have so far :

````
on:

  push:
    branches:
      - Sync_test
    paths:
      - 'dags/**'

jobs:
 name: "Test DAGs"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: dags
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install Poetry
        uses: /install-poetry@v1.3.1

      - name: Set up python
        id: setup-python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          cache: 'poetry'
          cache-dependency-path: 'airflow/poetry.lock'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          poetry env use ${{ steps.setup-python.outputs.python-version }}
          poetry install --no-interaction
        
      - name: 'Sync DAGs'
        uses: actions/checkout@Sync_test
        with:
          requirementsFile: requirements.txt
          dagPaths: '<dags path>'
          logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY```

Any idea would be much appreciated
````

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "push the files to the dags" (which files to which dags?), but note that `git push` does not push *files*, it pushes *commits*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By  "push the files to the dags" i meant synchronize the git repo on a commit for example,  with the dags folder in the bucket in google storage and have all the changes that were pushed to github appearing in the dag folder in airflow. Let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: If you only have one Git repository, there's nothing to sync. If you have multiple Git repositories, you use `git push` and/or `git fetch` and/or additional Git commands at the right point: push sends commits (and then asks/commands the other Git software to set a branch or other name in *its* repository), while fetch receives commits from the other Git software operating in the other repository. I know nothing of Airflow so I really can't help with anything on that side of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to push your codes from the dags folder of the repo to the GCS bucket using Github Action. If so, then first authenticate to gcloud and add the below command to copy the dags folder to GCS path

````
  - name: 'Copy DAGs to GCS bucket'
    run: |
      gsutil -m cp -R <repo's dags path>/* gs://gcs_bucket_name/<dags path>```
````